# ODE - Floquet theorem recommendations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please refer me to a good textbook or some papers about the Floquet Theorem (English)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Some useful public domain links

- [Michael Jeffrey Ward's lectures notes about](https://secure.math.ubc.ca/%7Eward/teaching/m605/every2_floquet1.pdf)
- [Giuseppe E. Santoro's lectures notes about](http://theory.fi.infn.it/SFTschool/SFT_2019/LectureNotes/Santoro.pdf)
- [E. Folkers' BCs thesis about](https://fse.studenttheses.ub.rug.nl/17640/1/bMATH_2018_FolkersE.pdf)
- [Proof wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Floquet%27s_Theorem)

Answer (score 0):

Linear System Theory by Wilson j. Rugh